# How to pass Interface Name and variable Name as a String in Java

Tags: java

**I have a interface and a String variable as below:**

```
public interface LoginPage {

    public static String UserName = "//input[@name='usertxt']";
}
```

Now I'm getting the interface name and variable name as String from Excel file as below:

```
String referenceName="LoginPage.UserName";
```

when I say `System.out.println(referenceName);` it should print `//input[@name='usertxt']` instead it is printing `LoginPage.UserName`
Please help me with this.

Comment: Consider using a Map (eg. [Hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)) or other mechanism to *pass data*, instead of relying on [*reflection*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+reflection) (keyword, if this is 'really the way it is to be done'). While reflection can do some neat things, the desire to [immediately] use reflection may indicate a lacking design/model..

Comment: Are you familiar with reflection? Or if there are not too many possible names, you can simply use a factory class to do this .

Comment: What do you think if you use an Annotation, it can work for you because it is more flexible against reflection. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html

Comment: Did you seriously tried it with double quotes surrounding it? Just wanted to know. If yes remove the double quotes.

Comment: Reflection API helped me. Thank for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection api:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

interface LoginPage {

    public static String UserName = "//input[@name='usertxt']";
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, ClassNotFoundException,
        IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        String referenceName="LoginPage.UserName";
        String s[] = referenceName.split("\\.");
        final Field field = Class.forName(s[0]).getDeclaredField(s[1]);
        System.out.println(field.get(null));

    }
}
```

Thanks to you, I learned this new thing today :)

for more details http://blog.sevagas.com/?Modify-any-Java-class-field-using-reflection

Comment: If the method is `static` you should to pass `null` to the `Field::get` method. This method usually takes an instance of the class for which the `Field` is defined, however, static fields are not associated with any instance, so you should provide `null` in place of an instance.

Comment: @flakes You are right.
Thanks :)
I made changes to the answer.